# Differences between transferFrom and safeTransferFrom

Tags: solidity, erc-20, smart-contract-wallets

What are the consequences of using "safeTransferFrom" for ERC20 instead of "transferFrom"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SafeTransferFrom performs a check to see it the token was indeed received by the other side (i.e. the 'to' address).

Some tokens do not return a bool on success, and if you use a wrong address for the erc20 (i.e. an address on the blockchain where there isn't a smart contract), the transferFrom will return bool true event if no transfer happened.

So it's always better practice to use safeTransferFrom when using someone else erc20.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.